# SendGrid PHP: Substitution and Section - Not working as expected

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

My Template is

```
Hi %first_name%,
This is %section_var%
```

My PHP code is

```
$request_body = json_decode('{
  "from": {
    "email": "team@grassrootsapp.in", 
    "name": "Team Grassroots"
  }, 

  "mail_settings": {
    "footer": {
      "enable": false
    }
  }, 

  "personalizations": [
  {
      "subject": "Accident Free Nation", 
      "to": [
          {"email": "saiy2k@gmail.com"},
          {"email": "team@grassrootsapp.in"}
      ],
      "substitutions": {
          "%first_name%": "Saiyasodharan" 
      },
      "section": {
          "%section_var%": "Section Text" 
      }   
  }],
  "subject": "Hello, World!",
  "template_id": "d6c26028-3765-461d-852e-43454115bc39"
}');

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($request_body);
```

The above code is working to some extent and I am having number of issues

1. It only replaces %first_name% and not %section_var%, that is `section` property have no effect.
2. I also tried moving `section` outside `personalizations` and putting it inside `sections` tag as given in documentation. But either there is no effect or I am getting `Bad request` error
3. For `substitutions`, I need to pass an array, with different value for each email ID. But If I change `substitutions` to array, it's throwing `Bad request` error. Setting the property `sub` also didn't help.

Looks like the current documentation and actual implementation is out of sync.

Comment: Have you got any answer yet? I'm facing the same problem...

Comment: Didnt find any solution

Comment: I appreciate that it's quite some time after you asked your question, but just in case you're still interested, I'd used the official SendGrid Library for PHP, rather than crafting the JSON body on your own: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#multiple-email-personalizations.